# syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT id FROM users WHERE ip' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php

I have been getting this error recently and I cant seem to fix it, I have looked at other similar questions and I cant seem to find anything that can fix this. I get this error when I try to run the code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT id FROM users WHERE ip' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\filesharing\assets\includes\user.php on line 24

Heres my code:

```
<?php 
include_once("connect.php");

function generateRandomString($length = 6) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}   

$random = generateRandomString();

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip_check = $conn->query"SELECT id FROM users WHERE ip = '" . $ip . "'";

if(!$ip_check) {
    die('Query failed to execute');
}

if($ip_check->num_rows == 1) {
    echo "User exists";
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($ip_check);
    echo $user;
} else {
    echo "User doesnt exist";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (ip, code) VALUES ('" . $ip ."', '" . $random . "')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }   
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

`query` is a method called on an object. Methods are like functions, they are called by their name which is *always* followed by round brackets. Arguments are placed inside those brackets.

That means you have to enclose the argument you hand over inside brackets, here the query string:

```
$ip_check = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE ip = '" . $ip . "'");
```

Which you can simplify to that, since php resolves scalar variables inside double quoted strings:

```
$ip_check = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE ip = '$ip'");
```

The official php documentation has a section about OOP which offers good examples about that stuff: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php